# setting Content-Type: in angular js post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, content-type

```
<input type="file" ng-model="articleimg" placeholder="upload related img">    

$http.post($scope.base_url+'create.php', 
            {params {view:'view',articleimg:$scope.articleimg}})
            .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
    });
```

I would like to know how and where to specify
the content-type: multipart/form-data in this angularjs post request?

Please assist.
the default seems to be "application/json, text/plain,"
which does not work with the image/file uploads.

```
if(isset($_FILES['articleimg'])===true ){
  echo "sucessfull";
}else echo "unsuccessfull";
```

the code above alway echos unsuccessfull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**$http.post** shortcut method in angular takes three parameters, url, request data and a config object in which you can set headers like below :

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

In your case it will be :

```
$http.post($scope.base_url+'create.php', 
        {params {view:'view',articleimg:$scope.articleimg}}, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
        .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
});
```

You can also construct the request object like below :

```
{
 method: 'POST',
 url: $scope.base_url+'create.php',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 },
 data: {params {view:'view',articleimg:$scope.articleimg}}
}
```

and then make the request like this :

```
$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

If you want to set common application wide headers , you can use default headers which will be added to all the requests by default like below :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

This will add the above mentioned content type for all the requests.

More information in the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: the "-" in the Content-Type is throwing and error. unexpected token.

Comment: Tried the second option " $http(req)" as well but it is just not showing up on the php server. when i try this if(isset($_FILES['articleimg'])===true ){
  echo "sucessfull";
}else echo "unsuccessfull";

Comment: adding the quotes did remove the error. thanks. but no lock on the sever side.