# Post Request in Ionic doesn't exist in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i was making a post request to my server from ionic app .

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient ,) {
  }

  logForm(){
    const obj = {appName:'oussama'}
    var link = 'http://www.samoox.com/SearchPaidApp.php';
    this.http.post(link ,obj,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

on the server side ii'm just trying to var_dump $_POST array but it returns array(0) {} , knowing that i've sent parametrs with the post request .

Comment: Could you please share also your code server side also where you are processing the Post request?

Comment: You did not specify _how_, “as what”, you are sending data. Add a `Content-Type` header with the appropriate value. Otherwise PHP will not know what it is supposed to do with this data, and therefor it will not populate $_POST. (In such cases, it can only be read directly from `php://input`)

Comment: @CBroe i dont know where to specify _Content-Type_

Comment: @edkeveked  it's only one simple line @var_dump($_POST)  i dont think the probleme is here

Comment: _“i dont know where to specify Content-Type”_ - well then _research_ it ...?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616136/setting-content-type-in-angular-js-post-request

Comment: Even if it is one line in your PHP, put it here; I don't think that your issue is a problem of content-type as @CBroe is suggesting it

Comment: @edkeveked   `<? php  var_dump($_POST); ?>`    here you are

Comment: @Samoox, do you mean that this single line is the method to handle your POST request server side?

Comment: @edkeveked _“I don't think that your issue is a problem of content-type”_ - unless angular adds a proper Content-Type automatically (don’t know, not using angular), I am pretty sure it is. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php: _“An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.”_ - send _anything_ else, and PHP won’t populate $_POST.

Comment: Try,     import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the content-type of your request

```
logForm(){
    const obj = {appName:'oussama'}
    var link = 'http://www.samoox.com/SearchPaidApp.php';
    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.append('responseType', 'text');
    var options =  {
            headers: headers
        };
    this.http.post(link ,obj,options).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you , but i still get this error 
`Http failure during parsing for http://www.samoox.com/SearchPaidApp.php`
wich i've avoided the first time by setting 
`responseType: 'text'`

Comment: @Samoox, I edited the answer. If it helped you, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted :)